# Question about Equivalence relation and Partition of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know these two definitions describe the same thing from two perspectives. But do the equivalence here mean if we take set $P$ contains all the equivalence relations on non-empty set $A$, and set $Q$ contains all the partitions of non-empty set $A$, then $P$ and $Q$ have the same cardinal number. So I think we need to build a bijection between $P$ and $Q$. Here are my thoughts.

My logic goes as follows. First, we need to build a mapping between $P$ and $Q$, then we need to show the mapping is both injective and surjective. (or invertible)

Step one, building the mapping. i.e. We need to show that **For any equivalence relation on $A$, we have and only have one partition of $A$,** and vice versa. The 'have' part is given in most textbooks, but the 'only have' part is confusing for me.

This question also arises from the original definition of 'relation' on set $A$ and the subset of $A \times A$.

The original definition is that for any $a,b \in A$, they should have the relation $R$ or not. By showing the two definitions are the same. Still, I think we need to build a bijection. A relation $R$ can easily be seen corresponding to a subset of $A \times A$ and vice versa, but how about the uniqueness?

I have a new idea, can we just show that $A/R$ is a mapping, i.e. the way we build the partition through equivalence relation is indeed a mapping.

For any equivalence relation, we can use $A/R$ to generate a partition, now I prove the partition is unique, then it satisfies the conditions to be a mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set, $\mathcal P_A$ the set of partitions of $A$, $\mathcal E_A$ the set of equivalence relations on $A$ and $\varphi_A$ the function

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\varphi_A : & \mathcal P_A & \longrightarrow & \mathcal E_A \\
    & P & \longmapsto & R = \{( a, b ) \in A^2 \mid (\exists p \in P) (a \in p \wedge b\in p)\}
\end{array}$$

You can prove that $\varphi_A $ is a bijection. Hence uniqueness.

Comment: Yes, but I think $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the same due to we use the equivalence classes to build the partition? If there exist some other ways to define a partition?

Comment: In my mind, the uniqueness part has nothing to do with the way we build it.

Comment: You say *In my mind, the uniqueness part has nothing to do with the way we build it*... which seems strange to me! Anyhow, I rewrote my answer to explicit a bijection between the set of partitions and the one of equivalence relations on $A$.

Comment: I understand, but still a question. I know how to show this 'mapping' is a bijection. But why it is a mapping.  By definition, I need to show that for any $P$ in $P_A$, there exists and only exists one $R$. The existence part is trivial coz I can always use the rule $\phi_A$. But how can I prove the unique part logically?

Comment: $R$ is perfectly and uniquely defined for a given $P$ which is enough as a relation is by definition a set of ordered pairs.